# Can I use a Windows Phone Developer Account with multiple devices?

Tags: windows-phone

Windows phone developer account works in a single mobile or multi mobiles?

Comment: I need a good clarification's guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can have up to three windows phones developer unlocked, per developer (you can relock, and change these [even if you no longer have access to the phones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), or they are otherwise not working)